# Find values of checked rows in gridview using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a gridview that looks like this:

```
<div id="btnCancel" onclick="cancelize()" class="btn btn-default pull-right ui-colour"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></div>
    <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        OnPageIndexChanging="gv_PageIndexChanging" Width="90%" PageSize="10" HorizontalAlign="Center" AllowPaging="true" OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound"
        CssClass="table table-bordered ui-state-default table-condensed table-responsive table-hover">
           <Columns>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="Nbr." ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
              <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" HeaderText="Options" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                     <div id="btnEdit" onclick="modalize(<%#Eval("id") %>)" class="btn btn-sm btn-default ui-colour"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span></div>
                  </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
              <asp:BoundField Visible="true" DataField="status" HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
              <asp:BoundField Visible="true" DataField="amount" HeaderText="Amount" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
              <asp:BoundField Visible="true" DataField="added" HeaderText="Added" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
              <asp:BoundField Visible="true" DataField="nextbilling" HeaderText="Next Billing" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
              <asp:BoundField Visible="true" DataField="lastresult" HeaderText="Last Result" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
              <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" HeaderText="Cancel" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label runat="server" Visible="false" ID="hfId" Text='<%#Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                     <asp:Label runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# " - " + Eval("cancel", "{0:d}") %>' ID="lblCancel"></asp:Label>
                     <asp:CheckBox ID="cbCancel" CssClass="cbCancel" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                  </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
           </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
 <a id="hlCancel" class="hlCancel" />
 <a id="hlEdit" class="hlEdit" />
```

Function to call modal:

```
             function cancelize() {
        var pId = queryString.pid;
        var ids = "";
        $("input[name$=cbCancel]:checked").each(function () {
            ids += "-" + $(this).next('input:hidden[id$=hfId]').val();//stuck here
        }).get();
        var url = "pageToView.aspx?id=1&pid=" + pId+ "&cids=" + ids;
        $j('#hlCancel').attr('href', url)
        $j('#hlCancel').click();
    }
```

everything works great, but on the .each() in the cancelize function it is returning undefined for the selected rows. What needs to change here so that it can pick up the hfId value from the rows with a checked checkbox?

Comment: [jQuery Get Selected Row Values from Asp.net Gridview on Checkbox Selection](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/10/jquery-get-selected-row-values-from.html) OR [Using jQuery with CheckBox and ASP.NET GridView](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=662) I think out of both one will definetly work for you.

Comment: @ManishGoswami unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work for me. I can only see name in lieu of id in the next() as a difference from the above. Tried it to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the parent `td` inside which both hidden control and checkbox are residing and then search the hidden field:-

```
  var Parenttd =  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').parents('td')[0];
  var HiddenValue = $(input:hidden,Parenttd).val();
```

Also, since you are using 'Visible=false' in your label control it will not render, instead you shoul use Hidden Control:-

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
```

**Edit:**
If you want to fetch this using ID selector then you need to set `ClientIDMode="Static"` property in checkbox and Hidden field control and then you can simply use like this:-

```
var parenttd =$('#cbCancel:checked').parents('td')[0];
var yourHiddenVal  $('#hfId',parent).val();
```

I have used this hidden control and checked the above jQuery code is working fine.

Comment: modified it so it will pull unique rows, works like this:    `var Parenttd = $(this).parents('td')[0];
var HiddenValue = $('input[name$=hfId]', Parenttd).val();`

Comment: @user4075691 - Okay Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing a value from the field. When an html checkbox is rendered, it will look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkbox">
```

`$('#checkbox').val()` will return 1 regardless of whether it's checked. If there is no value, it will return undefined - regardless of whether it's checked.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, I am trying to get the value of the hidden label hfId, not the value of the checkbox itself

Answer (score 0):

Use [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get your hidden label value.

```
$("input[name$=cbCancel]:checked").each(function () {
ids += "-" + $(this).parent().find('[id$=hfId]').val();
});
```

Also use style="visibility:hidden" or style="display:none" instead of using Visible="false" for your label tag because Visible="false" will stop the control from being rendered into the HTML.

Comment: I see your angle, but unfortunately it did not work. I believe this is because the issue is now the [id$=hfId]. I will Now try your edit

Comment: It did not work setting CSS, I also removed it so it was visible and it still did not work